# Determine whether 5V line has power using 3.3V IC (Atmega 2560) without burning power

Tags: atmega

We're using a 3.3V ATMega 2560 and we'd like to test whether a line (actually two lines) have 5V supplied or not, and we'd like to do this using as little power as possible. Are we better off testing intermittently using a P-Channel mosfet, or could we just use a high-value series resistor strait into the pin and not require an active components?

A long battery life and preferably low cost are key! A cheap mosfet won't break the bank though...

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Are you trying to minimise power from the 3.3V rail, from the 5V rail, or in total?

Comment: From the 3.3V rail mainly, but ideally from the 5V too if practical. The 5V rail is the charging rail for some li-ion cells, and the 3.3V runs from those cells (via a li-ion charger chip - MCP73871).

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcQL4A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When enable is 0V (from your microcontroller), M2 is off, and therefore M1 is off which means no current flows through R1 and R2.

When enable is 3.3V, M2 turns on, and pulls down M1 which will turn on M1, which allows current to flow through R1 and R2.

You can monitor the voltage across R2 and see if 5V is there (in this case a reading of 2.5V would indicate 5V). If its 0V, then you don't have 5V. As soon as you have your result, set enable back to 0V so you don't waste any current.

You can scale the resistors to give you whatever current is acceptable for you.

When you select your transistors, just watch out for the turn on voltages.

M2 needs a Vgs(th) such that 3.3V is sufficient to turn it on.
M1 needs a Vgs(th) such that -5V is sufficient to turn it on.

Comment: Thanks for this.

I already have a p-chan mosfet on the board for the high-side (i.e. M1), so that's easy, and presumably that has to be a mosfet rather than a transistor, unless the transistor's voltage drop is accounted for in the voltage divider.

For M2, presumably using an NPN-transistor (e.g. MMBT3904) instead of a mosfet there is fine.